# Animation a layout from bottom to top with fade in

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I want a animation that first **FadeIn** the `TextView` with id `Symbol_no` from *Bottom* to *Top* Then **FadeIn** other `View` on the screen.

```
symbolnotextview.animate().setDuration(duration).
    scaleX(1).scaleY(1).
    translationX(0).translationY(0).
    setInterpolator(sDecelerator).
    withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Animate the description in after the image animation
            // is done. Slide and fade the text in from underneath
            // the picture.
            mTextView.setTranslationY(-mTextView.getHeight());
            mTextView.animate().setDuration(duration/2).
            translationY(0).alpha(1).
            setInterpolator(sDecelerator);
        }
    });
```

But i think this is not what i mean to do .

Here is the XML of the design

```
  <LinearLayout        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:id="@+id/toplevel">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="15"
    android:background="@drawable/borderframe">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_btn_radio_to_on_mtrl_015"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="21477"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:id="@+id/Symbol_no"

        />

</LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Rohit Shrestha"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    />
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:paddingLeft="25dp"
    android:paddingRight="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/parentblock">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Block"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/block_no"
        android:background="@drawable/border"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:id="@+id/block_no"
        android:background="@drawable/border"/>



</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:id="@+id/class_container"
   >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Class"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/class_text"
           />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/room_no"
            android:textSize="25dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="8"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="40"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Seat"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="30dp"

            android:id="@+id/Seat_text"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/Seat_No"
            android:textSize="25dp"
           />

        </LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:text="Good Luck"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/display_notification"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Time_Left"
    android:text="5 hours to go"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:text="15 july,2015"
    android:gravity="center"

    android:layout_weight="10"/>
```

This is the output :

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by: "FadeIn the TextView with id Symbol_no from Bottom to Top" line

Comment: I mean this TextView
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="21477"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:id="@+id/Symbol_no"

        />
Must come from Bottom to Top then the other views must be displayed.

Comment: have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Symbol_no);
    DisplayMetrics dis = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, dis.heightPixels, 0);
    anim.setDuration(1000);
    anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0)
        {


        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0)
        {


        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0)
        {
            // show whatever you want to show after animation is finished.
        }
    });
    btn.startAnimation(anim);
```